# Python3: subgroup matches not working for OR '|' joined regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am attempting to parse some lines from a csv file to extract a series of digits. There are two possible formats, the digits alone, or the digits embedded in a longer code.

Here is a code example of what I am doing, and what is going wrong:

```
# regex works
>>> re.search('^(\d+)$', '5755').group(0, 1)
('5755', '5755')

# regex works with capturing group inside non-capturing group
>>> re.search('(?:^(\d+)$)', '5755').group(0, 1)
('5755', '5755')

# regex does not work as second of two non-capturing groups
>>> re.search('(?:\$SK-*(\d+)[-K])|(?:^(\d+)$)', '5755').group(0, 1)
('5755', None)

# the other regex of the pair works
>>> re.search('(?:\$SK-*(\d+)[-K])|(?:^(\d+)$)', '11$SK-2301-K13').group(0, 1)
('$SK-2301-', '2301')

# the regex works as the first of two non-capturing groups
>>> re.search('(?:^(\d+)$)|(?:\$SK-*(\d+)[-K])', '5755').group(0, 1)
('5755', '5755')
```

As you can see, the regular expression works fine by itself, or wrapped in a (?...), but when combined with another regex, the group of the second of the two regex's ceases working, even though the search returns a match object. However, if I then swap the order of the regex's that are piped together, the first one will still work regardless of which regex it is.

To be clear, when I combine two working regex's together with a pipe ('|'), the groups on the first one will work, but those on the second will not.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: `re.search('(?:\$SK-*(\d+)[-K])|(?:^(\d+)$)', '5755').group(0, 1, 2)`

Comment: You have a capture group in the left half of your regex, so it's only natural that the value of group 1 becomes `None`. Because _that_ group is now group 1, and the group you're looking for is now group 2.

Comment: What is happening is clear. What you are doing is not. Please explain what your real scenario is. Combining patterns with `|` is usually done manually, or when you build patterns from literal strings. Also see the [3rd and 4th cases](http://rextester.com/EGLOKL71791) where for the third case a branch reset group is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the issue are seeing is that an intuitive understanding of how the sub-groups work is not how they work in practice.

I'll expand on what two different comments on your question correctly point out. **Sub groups are not numbered as they are captured, but instead are fixed at creation/parsing of the regex.** For example:

```
re.search('match:(foo)','match:foo').group(1)
```

Will be

```
('foo')
```

Because the first capture group is `(foo)`. Similarly

```
re.search('match:(foo)(bar)','match:foobar').group(1,2)
```

Will be

```
('foo','bar')
```

As the first and second capture groups are `(foo)` and `(bar)` and each matched and captured.

In a pattern such as

```
match:(?:(foo)|(bar))
```

`(foo)` and `(bar)` are still the first and second capture groups, even if only one of them can possibly capture thanks to the OR `|`.

```
re.search('match:(?:(foo)|(bar))','match:foo').group(1,2)
re.search('match:(?:(foo)|(bar))','match:bar').group(1,2)
```

Will output

```
('foo', None)
(None, 'bar')
```

Therefore, you will need to add some logic to your code to check which of the capture groups has content and return that one.